# Robots.txt with WordPress and Joomla in same server

Tags: robots.txt

I have this configuration in my server root (hosted):

- root -> a Wordpress blog
- DirectoryJ -> a Joomla site
- DirectoryWP -> Another Wordpress blog

I don't know how to handle the robots.txt. Joomla 3.4 has a new robots.txt and it says I must move it to root. I did.

WordPress has his own virtual robots.txt, and my WP Sitemap Plugin says: don't create a robots.txt, so the plugin will add the www.xxx.com/sitemap.xml to the virtual robots.txt.

My robots.txt is this, in my root:

```
# If the Joomla site is installed within a folder such as at
# e.g. www.example.com/joomla/ the robots.txt file MUST be
# moved to the site root at e.g. www.example.com/robots.txt
# AND the joomla folder name MUST be prefixed to the disallowed
# path, e.g. the Disallow rule for the /administrator/ folder
# MUST be changed to read Disallow: /joomla/administrator/
#
# For more information about the robots.txt standard, see:
# http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html
#
# For syntax checking, see:
# http://tool.motoricerca.info/robots-checker.phtml

User-agent: *
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/administrator/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/bin/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/cache/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/cli/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/components/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/includes/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/installation/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/language/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/layouts/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/libraries/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/logs/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/modules/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/plugins/
Disallow: /DirectoryJ/tmp/
```

Do you think it's well configured? Or should i add:

```
Disallow: /wp-includes/
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /DirectoryWP/wp-includes/
Disallow: /DirectoryWP/wp-admin/
```

Comment: how is it a wordpress specific question? this is the wrong place to general robots.txt question

Comment: Well, i'm sorry if i post it in the wrong place, it's my first time here in stackexchange.com. 

This is a wordpress specific question because there's no doubt about robot.txt & Joomla, the question is about how to handle the 2 WordPress blog with that robot.txt file so Google can index my blogs content right with no conflicts.

Comment: But if you tell me how to move this question, i'll do it right now, how can i? Thanks.